# Download the index.html files from a large list of URLs

Tags: download-manager

I have a large list of URLs (150k) and I want a software (similar to httrack) to download the `index.html` file from the URLs.

The problem with httrack (Mac) is that it doesn't support importing URLs from a text file, therefore I reach maximum input character for terminal and cannot add all the URLs.

Both Mac and Windows are fine, but I prefer Mac.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul both Mac and Windows are fine, but I prefer Mac

Comment: Thanks! For each URL, do you want the entire website, or just index.html?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul the index.html file is enough
I want to be able to download page content (all text) and then I can index them in search platforms (like solr) to extract information from them.

Comment: @adelrahimi: Does it really have to be a file named `index.html` (not all servers use/provide these), or do you mean the files the URLs point to? Or are these URLs all from the same site, and you know that it uses `index.html` for every page? ·· How does your data look like? Could it be that it contains `http://example.com/foo/bar/hello.html`, but you want the tool download `http://example.com/` (or `http://example.com/index.html` specifically)?

Comment: @unor the tool (httrack) can locate and download all the links within a website e.g. (www.amazon.com) but I have all the sub-pages of a specific folder within a website e.g. www.amazon.com/product1 amazon.com/product2... product(N) etc.

Comment: I don't see the issue here. In WinHTTTrack you can specify files names, and recursion depth. Just edit your list to specify the full file names and paste it into the appropriate memo field in WinHTTrack.

Comment: @JanDoggen It's non a recursion it's a big list of specific page urls and I can't manually edit 150K urls.
I need a program to give it the url addresses and can download all the webpages simple as that.

Comment: You *can* edit 150k URLs if all you need to do is add 'index.html' to them. Use any text editor with macro capabilities. And you set your recursion depth to 'current/one level only'

Answer (score 3):

Just install [python](http://www.python.org), *if you are on windows - no need on OS-X or most Linux installs*, then open a terminal and type `pip install requests` to get the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library *on some platforms you will need to prefix with `sudo`* and you are good to go.

Assuming that your url file has one line per url:

```
python

import requests
n = 0
with open('url_file.txt') as infile:
     n += 1
     for line in infile:
         resp = requests.get(line.strip())
         if resp.ok:
             with(open('index_%06d.html' % n, 'wb') as outfile:
                  outfile.write(resp.content)
         else:
              print('Bad URL', line)
```

You could also use the [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) library to extract the data that you need from the pages.

All of the above is Free, Gratis & Open Source plus is cross platform.

Answer (score 3):

wget command can be used for this

```
wget --input-file=list.txt
```

this will store results in index.html, index.html.1, index.html.2 files. If you want to store results separately (e.g. create folder for each link you parse) then use the following format

```
wget --input-file=list.txt --force-directories
```